# How to structure an application without bundles in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Currently with Laravel 3 bundles, i have structured my application. For example, In a  hospital management system i would created each bundles for

- Channeling
- OPD
- Wards

etc.

But with Laravel 4, Bundles overridden by Packages. But after looking at  packagist, i think these kind of separation  is not suitable. So what will be the proper method for this?
Will it be the folder separation in application\controllers like,

application\controllers\

|--------Channeling\

|--------OPD\

|--------Wards\

and in models,

application/models/

|--------Channeling/

```
       |----------------Services/

       |----------------Some_Model_01

       |----------------Some_Model_02
```

|--------OPD/

```
       |----------------Services/

       |----------------Some_Model_03

       |----------------Some_Model_04
```

|--------Wards/

```
       |----------------Services/

       |----------------Some_Model_05

       |----------------Some_Model_06
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample structure you provided should work.
If the directories are defined in composer.json these files (including the files in sub-directories) will get loaded automatically

```
        "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
```